# How to get only the unique values out of a list of strings in C#?

Tags: c#, list, unique

Is there an easy way to get only the unique values out of a list of strings in C#?  My google-fu is failing me today.

(I know I can put them in another structure and pull them out again.  I'm looking for stupidly-easy, like Ruby's .uniq method.  C# has bloody well everything else, so I'm probably just using the wrong synonym.)

Specifically, this is coming from Linq, so if Linq had a built-in way to select only unique strings, that would be even cooler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
List<string> strings = new string[] { "Hello", "Hello", "World" }.ToList();

strings = strings.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: but dude... no boom shaka-laka?!

Comment: You see I just like BOOOM! But I wasn't sure if I should.. =P

Answer (score 6):

In .net 3.5:-

```
var strings = new List<string> { "one", "two", "two", "three" };
var distinctStrings = strings.Distinct(); // IEnumerable<string>
var listDistinctStrings = distinctStrings.ToList(); // List<string>
```

Boom shaka-laka!

Comment: You and your verbose examples, where is the dirty redundant cycle wasting code like mine!?

Comment: I spent the energy I could have spent on that, writing 'boom shaka-laka'!

Almost goes without saying ;-)